# Text and Image not lining up

Tags: html, css

I can't get my text and image to line up on the same line.  I've got a container called 'contactbar', then the text is h1, and the image is just in the html.  Please help...I've tried everything!!!
CSS:

```
#contactbar {
  background-color: #2E2B1F;
  width: 203px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #9A8478;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
  height: 56px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

and here's the html:

```
<div id= "contactbar">
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
  <img src="images/contactarrow.png" vertical-align="middle" width="21" height="35"    
vertical-align="middle" alt="linkedin"/>
</div>
```

Here's an image of what I'm looking for: http://www.flickr.com/photos/77703125@N07/8331407232/in/photostream

I've also tried absolute positioning, which works, but not the same across all browsers...so I'd like to steer clear of that.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a `margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;` to the ``<h1>`` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the image and heading to have a `vertical-align` value of `middle` seemed sufficient enough for me:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Which, with a bit of extra (non-crucial) styles, looks like this:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqggQ/5/